# How to start an application dynamically with second.html in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm developing a vue3 project.

main.js;

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
const app = createApp(App);
import store from "./store";
app.use(store);
import router from "./router/index";
app.use(router);
...

//just try...
app.mount("#app");
```

and my public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

And my App.vue;

```
 <template>
        <button @click=openNewPage()>create new page</button>
        <span>{{message}}</span>
        <router-view />
    </template>
    <script>
        methods:{
            openNewPage(){
                var t = window.open('second.html','newMonitor','height=700,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
    
            }
        }
    </script>
```

my store object;

```
export default createStore({
    state: {
      message:'Hello'
    }
});
```

and my second.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appSecond" style="height:100%">
        <template>
            <span>{{message}}</span>
        </template>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the second screen with the OpenNewPage method, I cannot access both the store object and the components I want to use do not work. I was try it;

second.js

```
const app2 = createApp({
});

export { app2 };
```

and my method

```
import { app2 } from "../second.js";
openNewPage(){
    var t = window.open('second.html','newMonitor','height=700,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
    
    if (t) {
        t.onload = function () {
        t.window.app = app2;
        app2.mount("#appSecond");
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I try to run in second.html but I get a warning like "[Vue warn]: Failed to mount app: mount target selector". The code didn't work anyway. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

`openNewPage()` can't run a script for the newly opened page; only the new page could run its own scripts. When `openNewPage()` tries `app2.mount()`, it's running that code on its own page (not the new one), leading to the error you observed.

### Solution

Remove the mounting code from `openNewPage()` so that it only opens the new page:

```js
export default {
  openNewPage() {
    window.open('second.html', …);
  }
}
```

Update `second.html` to load the script that mounts the app, and remove the unnecessary `<template>` within the `<div id="appSecond">`:

```html
<body>
  <div id="appSecond" style="height:100%">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
  </div>
  <script src="./second.js"></script>
</body>
```

In `second.js`, add the code that mounts your app:

```js
// second.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).mount('#appSecond')
```

Comment: I was try it, but i can't do it. Because when I add <script src="./second.js"></second> this result " second.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ", end try with this(<%= BASE_URL %>) but dont work

Comment: The `second.html` in the question does not contain that string, so you haven't really followed the directions in the answer, or you have an inaccurate representation in the question. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I changed my need in the project a little more and my question type has changed, I am sharing the link.
https://github.com/frknclskn/manyPageOneStore

Comment: The project you linked is completely different from the original post. You'll need to post a new question to cover this new use case so that someone familiar with the topic could answer. I'll chime in if I can.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this situation. I'm just looking for a solution and I couldn't find a solution for something like this question. I'm trying with different solutions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually what i need is clear;I'm developing an application in Vue3. What I need is to open and manage a particular component with window.open. I want my store(vuex) object to be the same on every page I open with window.open. E.g; Let my homepage have a value that says "Hello World" in an input and this is store->state->message:'Hello World'. I'm waiting for this post to appear on all windows I open. When I update this message on any page, I want it to update on all. Do we have such a talent?